# How to get a total time?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

Using VB6 and MS Access

Table:

```
ID Lunch_Intime, Lunch_Outtime

001 13:00:00 14:00:00
002 12:00:00 13:00:00
003 12:00:00 15:00:00
004 14:00:00 16:00:00
```

So on…

```
Lunch_Intime, Lunch_Outtime column data type is text.
```

I want to get a Total_Lunch_Time for the id.

Tried Query:

```
Select Lunch_Intime, 
       Lunch_Outtime, 
       Lunch_Outtime - Lunch_Intime as Total_Lunch_Time 
    from table
```

...but it's showing:

```
Total_Lunch_Time

#error
#error
```

So on..,

How to make a query for `total_Lunch_Time`?

Expected Output.

```
ID Lunch_Intime, Lunch_Outtime Total_Lunch_Time

001 13:00:00 14:00:00 01:00:00
002 12:00:00 13:00:00 01:00:00
003 12:00:00 15:00:00 03:00:00
004 14:00:00 16:00:00 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to converting your "time" values from text to date/time, I think you want to apply Format() to the elapsed times.

```
SELECT
    ID
    , Lunch_Intime 
    , Lunch_Outtime 
    , Format(CDate(Lunch_Outtime) - Cdate(Lunch_Intime), 
                "hh:nn:ss") AS Total_Lunch_Time 
FROM
    table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must cast the hours fields into date/time using CDate() before subtracting them.

Comment: e.g: 
Select Lunch_Intime, 
       Lunch_Outtime, 
       CDate(Lunch_Outtime) - CDate(Lunch_Intime) as Total_Lunch_Time 
    from table